# How do I compare records in MongoDB for uniqueness based on a field in python using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection with some records and I want to insert only unique values in the collection. I need to compare the new data with old to check if it already exists. If it doesn't exist, then insert it in the collection. I'm using pymongo - create_index(), but I don't know if it's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You Have To check if the record exists in the database or not

```
duplicates = collection.find_one(<query>)
```

Then if duplicates does not exist then Insert

```
# check duplicate
if duplicates == None:
    # Insert 
else:
    pass
```